# Unable to use result of Async DocumentDB operation CreateDocumentAsync

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, task-parallel-library, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a documentDB on Azure and can successfully create and get documents.

However, whilst documents are successfully created in the DB, I am not able to use the response from CreateDocumentAsync. The code immediately returns to the calling method on the controller. So the debug line is never reached.

Moreover I am setting the id to a guid, but the Document that is returned to the controller has an Id of 1.

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateNewApplication(dynamic data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("data was empty");
        }

        try
        {
            var doc = _applicationResource.Save(data);
            return Ok(doc.Id); //code hits this point and 'returns'
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Resource

```
  public async Task<Document> Save(dynamic application)
    {
        Document created;

        using (Client)
        {
            application.id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var database = await RetrieveOrCreateDatabaseAsync(Database);
            var collection = await RetrieveOrCreateCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, CollectionName);

            //persist the documents in DocumentDB
            created = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, application);

        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Application saved with ID {0} resourceId {1}", created.Id, created.ResourceId);

        return created;

    }
```

Get requests return data as expected:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetApplication(string id)
    {
        var application = _applicationResource.GetById(id);
        return Ok(application);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're not awaiting an asynchronous method:

This:

```
var doc = _applicationResource.Save(data);
```

Needs to be:

```
var doc = await _applicationResource.Save(data);
```

Your method should look as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateNewApplication(dynamic data)
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("data was empty");
    }

    try
    {
        var doc = await _applicationResource.Save(data);
        return Ok(doc.Id); //code hits this point and 'returns'
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yep that fixed it. Thanks for the speedy response. Thing is, I don't have this on any of my get methods that query the DB asynchronously and they all return as expected. Any idea why the difference? See edit on question.

Comment: Is your `GetById` method asynchronous? If so, it would return a `Task<T>`, not a `T`. Seems highly unlikely that it should work properly.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I speculate that the `Document` class has an `Id` property of type `Guid`. Or it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Just a style comment that might help make your code clearer, for async methods you can include that info in the method name.  A good example is the name `CreateDocumentAsync`.  For your method, instead of `Save`, call it `SaveAsync`